# How to check does element exist by tag?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I have an element on the page

```
<a data-cke-saved-name name></a>
```

and I want to check does this element exist on the page?
I tried this way

```
WebElement link = null;
    try {
        link = Main.s_driver.findElement(By.tagName("data-cke-saved-name name"));
        System.out.println("OK");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any other way to check this element?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It throws NoSuchElementException when element is on the page

Comment: So I guess this way is incorrect to search for this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. In this case I needed to specify that tag is empty through By.xpath

```
link = Main.s_driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-cke-saved-name, '')]"));
```

Comment: You can just use `//a[@data-cke-saved-name]`

Answer (score 0):

I used to use some times works for me

```
  if(driver.findElement(By.tagname("value"))!= null){
    System.out.println("OK");
    }else{
    System.out.println("Not there");
    }
```

Howerver `try.. catch()` also should be fine to check existing element as if not present then it will throw the exception

Comment: It's the same way, correct, but not in my way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use the expected conditions class if you do not need to use the element after checking that it exists.

```
bool exists = ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                              By.CssSelector("[data-cke-saved-name='name']"));
```

If you do need to use the element after finding out whether it exists or not, then you'll need to fall back to using driver.findElement. I'd either check that it exists first, or write a webdriver wait to poll until driver.findElement doesn't throw an exception.

Remember, data attributes count as css selectors. So you can use the CssSelector By instead of the slower XPath By :)

Comment: Mm. Interesting. I will try this way. Thank you.

Comment: "exists" variable gets the type WebElement, not boolean.

Comment: Look at that, it does. Sorry about that. Well then you can just change the  variable to WebElement instead of bool.

Comment: Basically all you need to do is do a driver.findElement() but catch the exception if the element doesn't exist

Comment: A. Now I've got the idea. Yeah, that's better if I don't need an object. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to select the best answer to your question :)